# How to convert from character to numeric and calculate p. adjust

Tags: r

In my data. table there is a column in which numbers are written in this format: `chr "0.190, 0.200, 0.600"`
my idea is this, I need to break this chr into separate elements: chr `"0.190", "0.200", "0.600"`
Then write these numbers as a vector to the p.adjust function, And then convert the result of p. adjust to char and output it to data. table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can first isolate the numbers and then convert them to numeric type:

```
x <- "0.190, 0.200, 0.600"
lapply(strsplit(x, ", "), as.numeric)
[1] 0.19 0.20 0.60
```

To combine the numbers into a vector, `unlist` the result:

```
vec <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, ", "), as.numeric))
vec
[1] 0.19 0.20 0.60
```

To calculate `p.adjust`, input `vec`and choose a `method`:

```
p.adjust(vec, method = "holm", n = length(vec))
```

Comment: thank you, but is it possible to combine these numbers into vectors somehow? c(0.19,0.20,0.60)

Comment: yes, it worked, but how to calculate p.adjust using lapply?

Comment: See edit again. Pls consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Everything is fine, but how do I convert them back to character and write them to data.table?

Comment: That's how you convert them back to character: `sapply(p.adjust(vec, method = "holm", n = length(vec)), as.character)`

Comment: and if I have a lot of such lists, how can I write them to data. table?

Answer (score 1):

An option will be using `str2lang` and `eval`:

```
x <- "0.190, 0.200, 0.600"
eval(str2lang(paste("c(", x, ")")))
#[1] 0.19 0.20 0.60
```

or using `strsplit` and `as.numeric`:

```
as.numeric(strsplit(x, ",", TRUE)[[1]])
#[1] 0.19 0.20 0.60
```

and

```
x <- "0.19 0.20 0.60"
as.numeric(strsplit(x, " ", TRUE)[[1]])
#[1] 0.19 0.20 0.60
```

Comment: That's OK so long as you trust the data. If the data comes from outside, it could be `x <- "1, file.remove('/etc/passwd'), 2"` or similar bad stuff.

Comment: thank you, but how to combine these numbers into vectors? c(0.19 0.20 0.60)

Comment: @ДмитрийЮзов see update `as.numeric(strsplit(x, " ", TRUE)[[1]])`

Comment: @GKi i see update but I don't understand how to make a vector out of them

Comment: @ДмитрийЮзов the output is a vector: `is.vector(as.numeric(strsplit(x, " ", TRUE)[[1]]))`

Comment: it doesn't work, it gives me the value TRUE, and I expect c(0.19 0.20 0.60)

Comment: `is.vector` tests if the supplied object is a vector.

Comment: @GKi ty, don't know how to calculate p.adjust for this vector?